# веб доступ к файлам

Tags: веб-программирование, laravel, vue.js, api, rest

В локальной сети находится папка, где хранятся видеофайлы. Когда-то давно было разработано ПО, одной из функций было занесение файлов в это хранилище, просмотр, генерация отчета по файлам (выборка, размеры). Сейчас пытаюсь перевести старое десктопное ПО на веб-рельсы (Laravel+Vue). После того как засерверил свои потуги на Апаче (виртуальная машина W10, сама сеть W7), выяснилось, что с обращением к файлам в сети из апача достаточно проблемно, пробовал символические ссылки, не получилось.
Подскажите, как в веб мире правильно организовывать этот процесс? Какой-то репозиторий с REST API, или что-то еще?

Comment: создайте сервер, который будет, используя существующее API, обрабатывать запросы с фронта

Comment: Проблема как раз и была в том, что не понятно, как обрабатывать запросы. Функция filesize возвращает результат, только, если файл находится на том же сервере что и апач. Советовали получить доступ к файлам с другого сервера через символическую ссылку, но функция возвращает ошибку, хотя кликая на ссылку в тоталкомандере перехожу туда и вижу файл.